May Jews eat chicken before the usual waiting time after eating hard cheese
According to Halacha, Jews should  wait at least 1 hour (according to some ashkenazi Poskim) or  6 hours (according to most Sephardic poskim) after eating Hard cheese before eating meat. Since chicken mixed with dairy is only forbidden Derabbanan, may they eat it before their usual waiting period is over after eating hard cheese (so long as they have cleaned  their mouth first)?

Just as a data point, most Sephardic communities do not differentiate between "soft" and "hard" cheeses: https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=2839&PageIndex=3

How is this different from the opposite case: cheese after chicken?

@יהושעק Indeed since waiting 6 hours is a sefardi thing and waiting after hard cheese is a minority Ashkenazi position, it comes out not a single Rishon or Gaon ever held to wait 6 hours after hard cheese.

Poskim do discuss how long to wait in general  (no waiting, one hour, six hours) and what type of cheese require waiting (soft not, hard yes, melted maybe not) but do NOT discuss differences between chicken and beef. See e.g., https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol5Issue5.pdf from p. 5 on

@mbloch Maybe no poskim in that pamphlet discuss it but that doesn't mean no poskim do.

Thank you @Double AA for your comment, I have edited my answer
Rema in Yoreah Deah 89:2- To wait 1 hour after eating hard cheese in order to eat chicken
Aruch Ha’shulchan Yoreah Deah 89:11/Badi Ha’shulchan 89:66/Halichot Shlomo Moadim page 383:footnote 16- to wait 6 hours after eating hard cheese in order to eat chicken
Pri Megadim Siftei Da’at YD 89:16 brings the Pri Chadash who held that the Zohar's one hour doesn't apply to chicken.
Link used: https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol5Issue5.pdf

Are the poskim you quote (outside of the Pri Megadim) refer to chicken or to meat?

@mbloch they are referring mainly to chicken
